# sshuttle connected but www.whatismyip.com still shows my own IP

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, ssh-tunnel, sshuttle

I am trying to use [`sshuttle`](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) to disguise my IP address, however without success. I use the command

```
sshuttle -r <user>@<remote_server> 0.0.0.0/0 -e "ssh -i /home/felix/.ssh/id_rsa" --exclude <remote_server> --dns -v
```

If I check my IP at `https://www.iplocation.net/` is shows the server IP. However, if I use `https://www.whatismyip.com/`, they still show my computer IP and IP location.

How is this possible? And what can I do to really disguise my IP robustly?

There are no error messages in the terminal where sshuttle runs, not even when I use more -v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: By default, `sshuttle` only tunnels IPv4 requests. `www.whatismyip.com`, however, evaluates the IPv6 address. To also tunnel IPv6 traffic, I had to change the command to

```
sshuttle -r <user>@<server> 0.0.0.0/0 -e "ssh -i /home/felix/.ssh/id_rsa" --exclude <server> -v --method tproxy
```

It only worked after I compiled a huge list of modules into my kernel, not sure which of them were really required. Definitely the socket modules for IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked, if you pass all connections as subnets, i.e.:

```sh
sshuttle -r <user>@<server> 0/0
```

`0/0` also includes IPv6.

Comment: That is a strange quirk in sshuttle's configuration. Even if it's a /0, normally an IPv4 mask never becomes an IPv6 mask.